# c++ dynamic linking : gcc option for symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, dynamic, hyperlink, lookup, symbols

Is there any compilation option available on gcc to prevent from symbol lookup error at runtime (and avoid to discover it at runtime by generating a compilation error)?

Actually, I have an undefined symbol at execution:

```
/path/to/lib/lib.so: undefined symbol _ZNsymbol_name_
```

Can gcc prevent the user from this problem at compilation?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with some more detail, perhaps with an example? If no example, at least what the situation is when you encounter this problem.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I just edited my question to show the kind of problem I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you added "/path/to/lib/lib.so" to the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If yes, is it the same lib.so which is used when you are building (compiling) or another one with the same name but in a different place?

Comment: I think we still need a bit more details: Why created `lib.so`, why isn't the symbol there [is it a different version than you expected, or something else gone wrong?]

Comment: Another tip, you can use `ldd <executable>` to list which shared libraries your executable links to.

Answer (score 2):

GCC will prevent this error at compilation, provided the relevant library has been provided for it link against.

If you have a different shared library, perhaps an older version installed, then it may well happen that you encounter this error even if the compilation was successful.

During linking you can use `ld -z now` to ensure that all the symbols will be resolved up front. Or you could use `export LD_BIND_NOW=1` to set the environment to ensure that all the symbols are resolved before the program runs.

Similar questions were answered for me [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422665/249817) and at useful tutorial I found [here](http://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/09/17/shared-libraries/).